# Style bundles in .NET 4.5 and icons in CSS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, minify, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I'm beginning to use .NET 4.5's built in minification and bundling to minify & bundle my CSS and JavaScript. JavaScript minification works great, however, I have run into trouble with CSS minification. I create a style bundle using the below code -

```
var myCss = new string[]
                                        {
                                            "~/Content/jquery.css",
                                            "~/Content/app.css",
                                        };
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/MySiteCss/").Include(myCss ));
```

and then I reference them in .cshtml (razor file) as below -

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/MySiteCss/")
```

It minifies the CSS file. However, if the CSS files contain styles that have background-image references, such as background-image: url('img/icon.png'), it attempts the load this icon file from a new location (derived from the bundle name) = /bundles/MySiteCss/img/icon.png

Since the icon does not exist in the location, it doesn't get loaded and displayed on the page.

Comment: Change it to an absolute url.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have your bundles and CSS served from the same place for this to work easily.  For example, change your bundle line to be:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/MySiteCss/").Include(myCss));
```

And update your reference as well:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/MySiteCss/")
```

Comment: I wish bundling would be smart enough to rewrite those paths while minifying, SquishIt can do it, others can do it too, so I don't see a reason why Microsoft's bundling could not do it.

Comment: @Giedrius This is definitely on the todo list

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in version 1.1.0-alpha1 of the Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework.
You can get the update via NuGet (https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization) if you include Prerelease.